# GET faved_at date from favorites with Twitter's REST API?

Tags: rest, date, twitter, favorites

Is there a possibility to get the date from when a Favorite was created through the REST API?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [documentation doesn't include a favourited date.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/favorites)

Comment: I opened an issue at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/438) to try to get them to add this feature.